# How to keep an inactive user logged in using JWT?

Tags: jwt

I'm creating a website that can also be used as a PWA. I'm using JWT for user authentication, and I'm storing the JWT in localstorage. I have a special use case where I need to keep my users logged in for at least 91 days even if a user just logs in once and never uses the site again for the next 90 days. To keep the user logged in for such a long duration, I'll have to set a high expiration time for the JWTs and from what I've read, that's not secure. Is there any way I can achieve my goal without making the site vulnerable?

I'm using Angular 8 and DRF.

Comment: Storing the access token (JWT) in localStorage is not a good idea.  It is better to keep the refresh token as an HttpOnly cookie and request a new access token (JWT) when the page loads.  Refresh tokens are meant to be long-lived, access tokens are not.  See this article for more information:  https://hasura.io/blog/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/

Comment: @jack.benson do PWAs (I'm talking about the installed app not a PWA being used in the browser) have access to cookie? Thanks for the link, I'll check it out.